# Why do we pop from the list at the end of each backtrack iteration?

Tags: python, recursion, recursive-backtracking

I have a solution to the following problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations/

```py
List[List[int]]:
        def backtrack(first = 1, curr = []):
            # if the combination is done
            if len(curr) == k:  
                output.append(curr[:])
            for i in range(first, n + 1):
                # add i into the current combination
                curr.append(i)
                # use next integers to complete the combination
                backtrack(i + 1, curr)
                # backtrack
                curr.pop()
        
        output = []
        backtrack()
        return output
```

My question is around `curr.pop()` why are we popping the `curr` combination each iteration? Shouldn't there be some condition like if `curr` is already in output?

Another question is for the recursion call `backtrack(i+1, curr)` - when this is called, am I right in saying that '`i+1`' takes the place of '`first`' in the main function?

Comment: In this code, `append` is playing the role of `push`.  And function calls work *exactly* the same whether they happen to be recursive or not.

Comment: `curr.pop()` is removing the last item in the list, which is `i` since it was added with `curr.append(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (copy of) the combination `curr` is output at the *deepest* *level* of recursion (well, it should be the deepest, currently the code continues looping even when it is known in advance to be futile i.e. to have no chance of producing any output, i.e. when the length of `curr` is *greater* than `k`).

The combination is built on the way in, one element at a time.

The element is added, the recursion is entered (and eventually the deepest level is reached and the copy of the combination is collected into the output) and then recursion unwinds, eventually getting out of that recursive call --- so we must remove the element which we've put in, so we can put the *next* element into the `curr`, on the next iteration *of that `for ... range ...` loop* (which *should* be guarded by `if len(curr) < k: ....`).

So yes, `i+1` *is* the *"new"* value of `first` -- in the *next* `for ... range ...` loop, *one level deeper*. Thus what's happening here is that the recursion in effect builds the nested loops structure where the deepest loop has the `curr` fully set and populated, and so adds it to the `output`.

Or in pseudocode:

```
   for i1 in range( 1, n+1):
      for i2 in range( i1+1, n+1):
         .........
            for ik in range( ik1+1, n+1):
               output.append( [i1,i2,...,ik1,ik] )
```

(except for the inefficiency in your code where it keeps creating more loops for `k+1`, `k+2`, ..., `n` levels potentially, even when we already know that it's all for naught as we only ever need the combinations of length *`k`*).

This is the gist of it, though your code does not build the `curr` while at the deepest level, as shown above, but rather by appending `ij` at each (`j`th) level. That's why it needs to `pop` it before appending the next value from the `for` loop, in effect *updating* the `j`th position in `curr`:

```
   for i1 in range( 1, n+1):
      curr.append(i1)
      for i2 in range( i1+1, n+1):
         curr.append(i2)
            .........
               for ik in range( ik1+1, n+1):
                  curr.append(ik)
                  output.append( curr )
                  curr.pop()
            .........
         curr.pop()
      curr.pop()
```

The same effect could be achieved by changing the `j`th value in `curr` directly. You'd need to create the `k`-long `curr` upfront for that (filled with some non-important values initially), and introduce an additional counter for that:

```
   for i1 in range( 1, n+1):
      curr[0] = i1                             # j == 0
      for i2 in range( i1+1, n+1):
         curr[1] = i2                          # j == 1
            .........
               for ik in range( ik1+1, n+1):
                  curr[k-1] = ik               # j == k-1
                  output.append( curr )
```

And that's what **(chronological) backtracking** is all about. Just ***nested loops***, each loops maintaining its state, ready to try another alternative when the control returns (backtracks) to it.

Also, that's what **"monads"** are all about. Just  ***generalized nested loops***, working in tandem  to produce the output from inside the *deepest* one, *no matter* how many levels there are above it.